# Deserealize map jackson in spring?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I have the following JSON

```
{
  "cmop": {
    "1001678": {
      "info": {
        "1005485": {"wt":1}
      }
    },
     "1001671": {
      "info": {
        "1005482": {"wt":2}
      }
    },
     "1001679": {
      "info": {
        "1005488": {"wt":3}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below are my model classes

```
public class Campaign {
@JsonProperty("cmop")
private CostDeal costDeal;
}
```

And the cost deal class

```
public class CostDeal {
private Map<String,CostDetail> costDetail;
}
```

And the cost detail class

```
public class CostDetail{
@JsonProperty("wt")
private int weightage;
}
```

I am getting the `costDetail` map object as null.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you "annotate" your json to tell us what each of the objects represent? I see a nesting of 5 objects in the json but you only have 4 classes to map those to:  `Campaign`,  `CostDeal`, the map, and `CostDetail`. There's also one non-mapped property in the mix called "info" so the question is: which json object should correspond to which class and what should "info" be mapped to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how you are parsing but considering that everything else is right and just to see your code piece you shared, you have added `@JsonProperty("cmop")` annotation at wrong place. It must be associated with your costDetail object as you are trying to must value of your json tag "cmop" in costDetail MAP.

```
public class CostDeal {
@JsonProperty("cmop")
private Map<String,CostDetail> costDetail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have a mismatch in your mapping (see my comment). Making some assumptions I added an additional class right below `Campaign` so here's a model that should be parseable (left getters and setters for simplicity):

```
public class Campaign {
    @JsonProperty("cmop")
    private CMOP cmop;
}

//the added class - choose a name as needed
public class CMOP {     
    private Map<String, CostDeal> deals = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void addDeal(String key, CostDeal deal) {
        deals.put(key, deal);
    }
}

public class CostDeal {
    @JsonProperty("info") //mapped to the "info" you have in your json
    private Map<String, CostDetail> costDetail;
}

public class CostDetail {
    @JsonProperty("wt")
    private int weightage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change model

```
Class Campain
public class Campaign { @JsonProperty("cmop") private Map<Long, CostDeal> mapCostDeal; }

Class CostDeal
public class CostDeal { @JsonProperty("info") private Map<Long, CostDetail> costDetail; }

Class CostDetail
public class CostDetail { @JsonProperty("wt") private int weightage; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added @JsonProperty("cmop") annotation at wrong place.

It must be associated with your `costDetail` object as you are trying to get the value of your json tag "cmop" into your `costDetail` MAP.

```
public class CostDeal {
@JsonProperty("cmop")
private Map<String,CostDetail> costDetail;
}
```